# Is the proper translation for あなたを構う 'I care about you?'

Tags: grammar

あなたを構う。

I know that 構う means kamau, which is 'to care' or 'to look after'. Google translate is unsure of the answer. A proper translation would be great.

Comment: It is probably 'care about you' (fragment), but without context it is hard to be sure. Do you have the source?

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about the "I care about you" that means "I have feelings to you"?

Comment: I think 構う is often used for caring about a situation (especially if a troubling one), not something that is affectionate. I could be wrong, but a sentence using 構わない usually refers to "not caring" about a situation (not "not having emotion towards it"), as in 今すぐ出たら構いますか。－＞いいえ、構いません。

Comment: 質問は、`Is the proper translation for あなたを構う 'I care about you?'`「『あなたを構う』の適切な英訳は"I care about you"ですか？」ですよね・・？（「"I care about you"の和訳は『あなたを構う』ですか？」じゃなくて）

Answer (score 1):

I would say 君のことを気にしてる, or あなたのことを気にしてます.

あなたを構う is definitely not what you want to say, if it even makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you wish to express I think. When myself and my wife are explaining to our kids why they can't do something dangerous, we often say 「ＯＯちゃんのことが好きだから気をつけて欲しい」or something like that. If you provide context perhaps I can help further.